# csv import error by copy command in sqllite

Tags: sqlite, import, importerror

i am importing a csv file data by

```
IMPORT mytable FROM 'E:/code playground/csv files/research.csv' WITH (format csv);
```

above command but gives error

> Execution finished with errors.
> Result: near "IMPORT": syntax error
> At line 1:
> IMPORT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no IMPORT SQL keyword/command in SQLite and thus the syntax error when you attempt to execute the statement.

You probably want to utilise the Import (File/Import) command available in DB Browser for SQLite.

**Demo**

Consider the following simple file:-

[image]

And the following empty database/connection:-

[image]

Then `File/Import/Table from CSV file....` and select the file:-

[image]

after clicking `Open`:-

[image]

The selecting the appropriate options and clicking `OK`:-

[image]

Then clicking `OK` :-

[image]